# <s:if> is not happening never, ever (with a doubleSelect behind)

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I'm having issues with a if-else construction using Struts2, doubleSelect and MySQL data. I can get proper details from DB, and I can put it into all variables needed ... but the s:if is not working at all, always fall down into else.

Any help, please?

I've tried to use different variables (list, doubleName, name) ... but no luck:

```
<s:if test="%{#list=='Busy'}">Busy</s:if>
<s:else>
    <s:doubleselect headerValue="--- Some Header ---" headerKey="" 
        doubleHeaderValue="--- Some Header ---" doubleHeaderKey=""
        name="name" list="list.keySet()"
        doubleName="doubleName"
        doubleList="list.get(top)"/>
</s:else>
```

I want to show message "Busy" if the content of the list is "Busy" ... and the doubleSelect with all the lists inside if not (this part of the doubleSelect is working 100% perfect).

Please, let me know if you need some more code (like .java class with getters/setters or anything else).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `#list` the length of `list`?

Comment: What's `#list`?

Comment: list is "the list" that I fulfilled with DB values. It always prints a doubleSelect where the first combobox has its own list of items in the second combobox.
I detect in the java file if the first value is "busy" and I write that exact word. So I want in the front-end (JSP with struts2) to detect if the item is "busy" or "available". If busy, just print "Busy", if "available", then print the options taken from DB.
Is this more clear now?

Answer (score 0):

The expression might not be evaluating correctly if you are comparing Strings using the `==` operator. Try using `.equals('Busy')` instead.

As in:

```
<s:if test="%{#list.equals('Busy')}">Busy</s:if>
```

Comment: Hi! Ok, I think I got the point ... but I don't know how to do it. What I need is to check with the if sentence the first value of the list. Something like list[0] == "Busy" Is there anything like this that could actually work? Thanks!!

Comment: You could try `<s:if test="'Busy' in list">` using the _in_ operator as referenced in
[Struts 2 OGNL](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/ognl.html).

Comment: It's a really good approach! But I'm not able to get working. I've tried: <s:if test="'Busy' in #list"> <s:if test="'Busy' in #{list}"> and <s:if test="'Busy' in {#list}"> with no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, the question was awfully asked. Some points:

- I was actually using MAP instead of any list to create and add the values to the doubleSelect comboboxes.
- To access the variable list, through OGNL I have correctly put a getter called getList in the java class.
- Finally, to check if a value (actually, a KEY) is contained in the MAP there is a pretty good method called: containsKey(keyValueSerched), so the if sentence that worked for me is:

  s:if test="list.containsKey('Busy')">
      BUSY
  /s:if>

Thanks everybody for helping me.

Happy coding!

PS: Please note that, for a unknown reason I cannot post the code with proper format, and actually to be seen I have to remove the first "<" from the s:if tag.